# How can I return a variable from a $.getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope, return-value

I want to return `StudentId` to use elsewhere outside of the *scope* of the `$.getJSON()`

```
j.getJSON(url, data, function(result)
{
    var studentId = result.Something;
});

//use studentId here
```

I would imagine this has to do with scoping, but it doesn't seem to work the same way *c#* does

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yeah, my previous answer does not work because I didn't pay any attention to your code. :)

The problem is that the anonymous function is a callback function - i.e. getJSON is an async operation that will return at some indeterminate point in time, so even if the scope of the variable were outside of that anonymous function (i.e. a closure), it would not have the value you would think it should:

```
var studentId = null;
j.getJSON(url, data, function(result)
{
    studentId = result.Something;
});

// studentId is still null right here, because this line 
// executes before the line that sets its value to result.Something
```

Any code that you want to execute with the value of studentId set by the getJSON call needs to happen either **within** that callback function or **after** the callback executes.

Answer (score 67):

> it doesn't seem to work the same way
>   c# does

To accomplish scoping similar to C#, disable async operations and set dataType to json:

```
var mydata = [];
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
    mydata = json.whatever;
  }
});

alert(mydata); // has value of json.whatever
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, as getJSON is an async call, so the variable set in the delegate is not accessible before the async call is finished.

Comment: Interestingly enough I had "&callback=?" in my URL which seemed to override the async:false setting.

Comment: Been searching everywhere - none of the above answers work for me, but this one does!

Answer (score 25):

Even simpler than all the above. As explained earlier `$.getJSON` executes async which causes the problem. Instead of refactoring all your code to the `$.ajax` method just insert the following in the top of your main .js file to disable the async behaviour:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
 });
```

good luck!

Comment: this is must be the top answer

Comment: Agree with @MostafaKing

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Thank you @bicycle.

Comment: Note that this means that your page stops loading until all ajax requests are done. Ajax uses async for a reason: all ajax calls are executed in the background and your page can display the results of each request as soon as it gets in. It makes sense learn how to work with callbacks and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish delegate to other functions you can also extend jquery with the $.fn. notation like so:

```
var this.studentId = null;

$.getJSON(url, data, 
    function(result){
      $.fn.delegateJSONResult(result.Something);
    }
);

$.fn.delegateJSONResult = function(something){
  this.studentId = something;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var context;
$.ajax({
  url: 'file.json',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {   
    assignVariable(json);
  }
});

function assignVariable(data) {
  context = data;
}
alert(context);
```

Comment: The question was asked about 9 years ago and your answer is not adding any significant improvement to answers already posted.

Answer (score -2):

hmm, if you've serialized an object with the `StudentId` property then I think that it will be:

```
var studentId;
function(json) {
    if (json.length > 0)
        studentId = json[0].StudentId;
}
```

But if you're just returning the `StudentId` itself maybe it's:

```
var studentId;
function(json) {
    if (json.length > 0)
        studentId = json[0];
}
```

Edit: Or maybe `.length` isn't even required (I've only returned generic collections in JSON).

Edit #2, this works, I just tested:

```
var studentId;
jQuery.getJSON(url, data, function(json) {
    if (json)
        studentId = json;
});
```

Edit #3, here's the actual JS I used:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageName + "/GetStudentTest",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{id: '" + someId + "'}",
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

And in the aspx.vb:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetStudentTest(ByVal id As String) As Integer
    Return 42
End Function
```