# How to use jQuery ajax data to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following javascript code:

```
function initSite(){
    var site;
    $.getJSON(www+'init/initSite', function(data) { site = data; });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var site = initSite();
        console.log(site);
}
```

which returns *undefined*... how can i store the json object that i recieve in the site variable so i can use it later?

**EDIT:**
This seem to work but im not sure if its correct to use this solution

```
var site = null;
$.ajax({
  url: www+"init/initSite",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    site = data;
  }
});
console.log(site);
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: then how the heck am i supposed to use the isloggedin variable that i get from the ajax query in javascript to limit user actions if he's not logged in..

Comment: Use callbacks, like `getJSON`.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31129/497356

Comment: there's no **heck**, it's a simple miss concept. You can initialize everything from the result call, no need to initialize **only** when the DOM is ready... see the answers.

Comment: what if i use $.ajax({}) with async:false? This seem to work... is there any problems that can come up with this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you got *undefined* because your function doesn't return anything and the ajax call is also asynchronous, so you have to wait the server response. Since `$.ajax` (and shortcuts) returns a promise you can do this task using deferred

```
function initSite(){
    return $.getJSON(www+'init/initSite');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(initSite()).done(function(data) {
        /* continue here the code execution, e.g. call another function */

        doAllTheRemainingWorkWith(data)

    });
}
```

as you can see this code is short and easy to read

Comment: but my code is way too much to put it in the function there... is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: inside the `done()` just call another function passing data returned

Answer (score 1):

```
function initSite(onSuccess){
    $.getJSON(www+'init/initSite', onSuccess);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   initSite(function(data){
       var site = data;
       // initialize your code.
   });
}
```

Comment: my current javascript code is over 2000 lines of code... do i have to put all the code where you call the function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just a miss concept:

`getJSON` is an async call, and the `site = data;` will only happen way after the DOM is ready.

in order for you to make everything work the way it should, your initialization needs to start from your async call result and never before, for example:

```
// no need to wait for DOM ready to call `initSite`
initSite();

function initSite() {
    $.getJSON(www+'init/initSite', function(data) {  
        initialization(data);
    });
}
function initialization(site) {
    // initialize all the things that need to be done
    console.log(site);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // do other stuff, for example show a loading message/image
}
```