# Assign results of JSON to array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete

I would like to take the results of my `$.getJSON` and place that JSON data, specifically the facility. FacilityName, as the values for the array availableTags.  I have tried executing a function call where you see the // TODO: but I am not getting this sorted out.  I'm sure it is easy for your jQuery experts!  I DO see the facilities displayed on my page in the `<div id="info"></div>` tag as I would expect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker();
});

var names = [];

$.getJSON('FacilitiesAsync','sourceDb=myDb',processFacilities);
function processFacilities(data) {
    $.each(data, function (facilities, facility) {
        names += facility.FacilityName;
    }); // end of each

    alert(names);

    $("#tags").autocomplete("source", names);
};

$(function () {
    $("#tags").focusout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert("Testing");
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert("Done!");
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: *Inside* the getJSON callback: `$("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: somehowUsingTheJSONResponseData
    });` (I believe `source` can also be a *function*.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/how-can-i-return-a-variable-from-a-getjson-function/31153#31153

Answer (score 0):

your TODO block contain inside of self invoking anonymous function, probably it executes before your `getJSON` executes, so in time of TODO block executing there is no json data. try to access data after `getJSON` function, may be in callback or within `done` of the `getJSON`.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  HOW do I call the callback function to load the data for the autocomplete?  So the page loads and this JSON data is returned in the background with an ajax call.  Once I have all the data it will be available in the autocomplete input control

Comment: Something happened to the post made by another user that was helping me

Comment: I get the results I always had.  I want to see them in the autocomplete.  That is still not working.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI for autocomplete?

Comment: But you didn't mention that in your question, that's why I ask, hence refer [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) it seems your `autocomplete` have syntax error. And try with raw data for check whether it works

Comment: I have done exactly that before I posted this question.  It works with the raw data but I want to display my JSON data.  That data looks like a comma separated list of strings without quotes.

Comment: I have a valid json string returned from my service.  I JUST want to take that string and make it the values that show up in autocomplete.....please

Comment: ok, then are you sure about `names` contains array contains list of strings at `autocomplete` functoin calling? If it is, there should be another problem which caused to stop autocomplete functions execution properly.